# jQuery finding child elements of <table>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to execute a function for each "tr" child element of my "table" with jquery, but this code does not identify the children. I've used this code for "div" based designs before and it works perfectly if I change the "table" and "tr" tags to "div" but it doesn't run here!
This is simple design:

```
<table id="tblSearch" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hey</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>There!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr align="center">
        <input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" />
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
        var a = $("#tblSearch").children("tr").each(function(){
            alert($(this).text);
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/hULDj/198/)
Note that the alert is run just once! And I have also removed the "tr" for children in my jsfiddle to make the code runnable...
could anyone help me?

Comment: your html is invalid.. there are no `td` inside your `tr`

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I've removed "td"s here for simplicity only.

Comment: If you are introducing new problems by reducing the example, how should we know that the real problem is?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'd keep that in mind! :)

Answer (score 8):

The `tr` elements are not children of `table`, the are children of [`tbody`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) (or `thead` or `tfoot`). The `tbody` element is automatically created if you don't specify it. You can figure this out easily for yourself if you inspect the generated DOM.

Long story short, either search for all descendants, with `.find`

```
$("#tblSearch").find("tr")
// simpler:
$("#tblSearch tr")
```

or include `tbdoy` in your selector:

```
$("#tblSearch").children("tbody").children("tr")
// simpler:
$("#tblSearch > tbody > tr")
```

That being said, you also have to add the actual content inside `td` elements, as noted in the other answers.

---

If you are new to HTML and tables, read the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

Comment: Its completely acceptable for `tr` elements to be direct children of `table` if `tbody` is omitted. The linked MDN docs state this.

Comment: I never said that it isn't. But the selector won't work because `tbdoy` is automatically created.

Comment: Thanks @Felix, you solved my problem. I didn't know about tbody.

Comment: Is this certain to happen in all user-agents?

Comment: @spender: Actually it looks like `tr` elements are not valid children in HTML4 (http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE), but they are in HTML5 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element).

Comment: @FelixKling : Thanks for taking time to follow up my question.

Comment: @spender: Also, I'm not sure how exactly the HTML is converted to the DOM, but if we assume that it uses the DOM API to add the rows, the `insertRow` methods states *"In addition, when the table is empty the row is inserted into a TBODY which is created and inserted into the table."* . Can be found both in HTML4 and HTML5. That would explain why a `tbody` element is created (that's the only thing I could find regarding this topic).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems, an invalid html and the selector is wrong

```
<table id="tblSearch" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hey</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>There!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
        var a = $("#tblSearch").find(">tbody > tr").each(function () {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pp7tc/)

Comment: just like Felix, thanks Arun. tbody was the big problem. And thanks for the fiddle :)

Answer (score 2):

Problems were:

- `tables` automatically have `tbody` elements inserted into the DOM, so you should not reference `TR`'s as children of a `TABLE` element.
- You referenced a non-existant `text` property instead of the jQuery `text()` function.
- You probably want to reference the `td`s anyway (and probably only a specific TD in each row), as returning the text of an entire row (`TR`) seldom makes sense in HTML.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/TdGKj/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
        var a = $("#tblSearch td:first-child").each(function () {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    });
});
```

The `#tblSearch td:first-child` selector basically says: "Find the element with `id=tblSearch` then search for any `td` elements that are the `first child` of their parent. Note I added a second column of dummy TDs cells to the JSFiddle so you could see this in practice.

There any many selectors for choosing specific children, which will vary based on your specific needs, but that just needs a little research of [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use children at all. You can just create a selector -

```
$('#tblSearch tr td')
```

**WORKING DEMO -** http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/Aiwgm

First you need to fix your HTML structure, place the child td elements inside each tr -

```
<table id="tblSearch" border="1px">
    <tr> 
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hey</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Hi</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>There!</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div>
<input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search"/></td>
</div>
```

Now you can alert each value using this javascript snippet -

```
$(function () {
  $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
     $("#tblSearch tr td").each(function(){
          alert($(this).text());
      });
  });
});
```

Note - This will alert each value separately as you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems in the question you provided:

1. Your HTML is not valid; Place a `td` element inside each `tr`
2. Call the correct jQuery function.  Instead of using `children('tr')`, which it won't find because there are no `tr` that are children to the `table` element (only `tbody`,`thead`, etc), you will need to call the `find()` jQuery function (e.g. `find('td')`) and from there you will be able to get the text of the cell; however, you may also be able to find `tr` and get text of the whole row in that case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all fix up your html and add the correct tags around the cell data

Then this should do what you're wanting:

```
 $('table#tblSearch tr').children().each(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
 });
```